# What is wrong with Vue and lodash debounce?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

The props:

```
props: {
  delay: Number,
}
```

The watcher:

```
 watch: {
   q: _.debounce(function() {
     console.log(this.delay);      // 500; always works fine, this.delay is here
   }, this.delay)                  // never works; 
 },
```

If hardcode a delay (set `500` instead of `this.delay` - it works; otherwise - function not debounce).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried what happens when you define a function as watcher for q that does self = this and pass self.delay as argument?

Comment: watch: {
    q: function() {
      let self = this;
       _.debounce(function() {
        console.log(self.delay);
      }, self.delay)
    }
  },

- not work at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to accomplish setting the `delay` there. `this` is not the component in that scope. You can use `$watch` instead inside a lifecycle hook:

```
created () {
  this.debounceUnwatch = this.$watch('q', _.debounce(
    this.someMethod,
    this.delay
  ))
},

destroyed () {
  // Removed the watcher.
  this.debounceUnwatch()
},
```

For more information:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch

### Edit

This doesn't work either. It just really seemed like it should have. What I think needs to be done here is you need to debounce whatever is updating `q` and not `q` itself.

Comment: Thanks. But why is `this` available inside function that passed to _.debounce, if it's not in the scope?

Comment: lodash handles passing that for you.

Comment: This is wrong. You'd need call a debounced *method* and only update `q` in that. I'll update my answer.

Comment: You'd likely want to debounce whatever is updating `q` instead of `q` itself here.